# How to use functions from other classes/files? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, scope

I've been searching the web and have read for hours with no luck. Possibly because it is so basic, maybe because I'm confused about the terminology. (Quite the noob here.) Picking up a book soon, but until then, maybe someone can clarify this for me.

I'm making a simple rpg style game. I have multiple files. MainClass.as, Hero.as, FrontEnd.as, & Levels.as.  I made them all public classes. I have a function called gotoMainMenu() in FrontEnd.as, and a variable named currentHP in Hero.as. I want to make a function that checks the currentHP and

```
if(currentHP <= 0) {gotoMainMenu()}
```

from what I've read I need to instantiate FrontEnd.as in my Hero class to access its functions... but it doesn't work for me. All the files are in the same folder. I've tried this:

```
var frontend:FrontEnd = new FrontEnd();
addChild(frontend);
if(currentHP <= 0) {frontend.gotoMainMenu()}
```

but that doesn't work either.
also tried to import the class...
How do I access functions and variables from another class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AS3 - Call a method between classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060513/as3-call-a-method-between-classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do here, is something called "dependency injection"

Instead, of creating a new instance of frontEnd in your hero class, you want to pass in the instance of frontEnd that allready exists on the stage into your hero class.

So for example, you might have your constructor of your heroclass look like this:

```
public function Hero (frontend:FrontEnd) {
this.frontEnd = frontEnd;
}

And then you can do 
if(currentHP < 0 ) { frontEnd.gotoMainMenu()};
```

If you need to inject more than 3 classes into your class, you should start thinking about injecting through properties rather the constructor.

You class would look like this:

```
package {
public class Hero {

    public var frontEnd:FrontEnd;
    public var levels:Levels;
    public var weapon:Weapon;

    public function Hero() {

    }

    public function fire(){
        if(weapon){
        weapon.fire();
        }
    }

    public function getHit()
    {
       if(frontEnd)
       { 
         if(currentHP < 0) { frontEnd.gotoMainMenu();}
       }
    }
    public function increaseScore() {
        if(levels){
            levels.increaseScore();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Then, when you instantiate your Hero class it would look like this:

```
var hero:Hero = new Hero();
hero.levels= levels;
hero.frontEnd = frontEnd;
hero.weapon = machineGun;
```

Alternatively, you can use a dependency injection framework such as RobotLegs2 to do this work for you. https://github.com/robotlegs/robotlegs-framework

However, that isn't the correct way to handle things in this case.
In this particular case, what you REALLY want to do, is Dispatch an Event.

So, you would have:

```
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.Event;
public class Hero extends EventDispatcher{


}
```

and then in some function you would write:

```
if(currentHP < 0 ) {dispatchEvent(new Event(DIED));}
```

And then in the Class in which your Hero is sitting, you would do something like this:

```
addEventListener(Hero.DIED, handleDeath);

private function handleDeath(e:Event){
  frontEnd.gotoMainMenu();
}
```

One of the great advantages of dispatching an event, is that you can have multiple things listen to the same event.  Or you can even switch what listens to the event.

so you could do:

```
if(hasRessurection)
{
  hero.addEventListener(Hero.DIE, restartLevel,false,0,true);
  town.addEventListener(Hero.DIE, increaseRessurectionCost, false,0,true)
} else {
  hero.addEventListener(Hero.DIE, gotoMainMenu,false,0,true);
}
```

Comment: C:\...\Flash Files\Hero.as, Line 10 1017: The definition of base class EventDispatcher was not found.
do I need to make a BackEnd.as file that handles these things somehow? and what if I wanted to call functions from multiple classes? like public function Hero (frontend:FrontEnd, levels:Levels, )?

Comment: You need to import EventDispatcher.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586830/inherited-a-class-from-eventdispatcher-in-flash-but-custom-event-not-received

And yes, if you need to access more classes, you can inject more classes.  Once you start having more than 3 classes to inject, I would use another method which I'm adding to the answer now.