# A class needs to be able to see a variable in Main AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop, flash-cs6

I'm working with Flash CS6 and FlashDevelop and all the similar questions I could find deal with classes accessing stuff in other classes, but not in Main so here it is:
My main initializes the level i made in Flash like so:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip 
{
private var MazeNr1:Level = new Level();

public function Main():void 
{
    if (stage) init();
    else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}

private function init(e:Event = null):void 
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    addChild(MazeNr1);
}
}
```

And I need my instantiated level variable (MazeNr1) to be seen by other classes in my project so that I can use its parameters (like width and height which are not the same thing as stage.parameters). Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AS3 - Call a method between classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060513/as3-call-a-method-between-classes)

Comment: There are no special rules for `Main` except the fact that it's called first. The other answers you mention should apply here

Comment: What you're talking about doing with MazeNzr1, Main, and other classes is what's called a circular reference.  Main contains class X (either directly or through another class), and class X references Main.  Avoid circular references at all reasonable costs!  They will hurt you in the long run.  Instead you should use Main to pass references of MazeZr1 to other classes, which will then hold their own references to MazeZr1 and never have to use circular reference back to Main.  Either that, or use callbacks or event listeners of some sort (which will also cut out the circular reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Main` is your document class, you could do this a few different ways.

1. As mentioned in another answer, make your variable public.  Then access it like so:

   ```
   Main(root).MazeNr1
   ```
2. Make it a static variable

   ```
   public static var MazeNr1:Level;

   public function Main():void 
   {
       MaxeNr1 = new Level();
       //rest of your constructor code
   }
   ```

   Then you can access it in any scope simply by doing this:

   ```
   Main.MazeNr1
   ```

Comment: This worked just fine. But I'll try and figure out the way to do it all proper with a reference simulation now. Thank you, kind sir.

Answer (score 1):

Make the variable 'public':

```
public var MazeNr1:Level = new Level();
```

Then you can access it from outside the class.

Comment: This, by the way, didn't work as a straight up solution. Besides, making stuff public just for the sake of accessing from another class is bad design practice.

Comment: "A class needs to be able to see a variable in Main AS3". The answer addressed this concisely. Making properties publicly accessible is perfectly good practice.

Comment: Well for AS3 in a FlashDevelop project this didn't work. It only made it visible when I declared it as static.

Comment: The public keyword makes instance variables accessible on instances of a class. Static variables (also called class variables) are synonymous with global variables which are best used sparingly to keep code well structured. To learn more about this topic, research "class variables vs instance variables".